# Let users set parameters in console in R

Tags: r, function, user-interface, console

I have the code, that I want to convert to a more user-friendly one.

```
load_data <-get.Comtrade( c="2"  #Country
                              ,t="x"  #Time
                              ,m="y"   #Model
                              ,s="z"   #Size

# Convert to dataframe
data_2021 <- as.data.frame(load_data$data)
```

I want to allow users to set parameters in Console, like this:

```
Please specify the Country: 
Please specify the Time: 
Please specify the Model: 
Please specify the Size:
```

And to run the function, after they define all these parameters

Comment: Look at `readline`.

Comment: Also `menu()` is a possibility if some of the parameters (like, country, model and size, perhaps) come from a fixed set of options.